# With Python:Trying to save a Random Number in an array to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, random

Hi I am trying to save a Random Number to the MySQL database. I have created a database called "RandNum1" and when I try to create the Random Number as an array I get a Type Error:"'str' object is not callable" error.
Here is what I have done so far:

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="RandNum1"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
import numpy as np
randnums=np.random.randint(1,20,1)

sql = "INSERT INTO RandNum (randnums) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.execute(sql(randnums))
connection.commit()
```

The error is produced on this line:

```
mycursor.execute(sql(Randnums))
```

I am a newbie to Python and MySQL...any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`execute` takes two arguments - the SQL string and a tuple of values:

```py
mycursor.execute(sql, (randnums,))
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting yet another error:

Comment: the error is: python type numpy.ndarray cannot be converted

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the code for saving the random numbers to a database (I had to abandon the Numpy part, although if anyone knows how to do that, I'd be eager to know how)***

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="RandNum1"
    )
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
import random
randnums = random.randint(1,20)
print(randnums)
val = (randnums)
sql = "INSERT INTO RandNums (RandNum) VALUES (%s)"
mycursor.execute(sql,val)
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) inserted.")
```

***And here is how to print the record:***

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="RandNum1"
    )
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM RandNums"
mycursor.execute(sql)

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)
```

Comment: I just noticed I copied an incorrect version of the code...you need to put val = randnums AFTER sql = "INSERT INTO ..."...not before it.

Comment: val = ("randnums")*

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the corrected code:***

```
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
   host="localhost",
   user="root",
   passwd="",
   database="RandNum1"
   )
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
import random
randnums = random.randint(1,20)
print(randnums)
sql = "INSERT INTO RandNums (RandNum) VALUES (%s)"
val = ("randnums")
mycursor.execute(sql,(randnums,))
mydb.commit()
print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) inserted.")
```